# Why I cant parse this JSON String with JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this JSON String:

```
[{'Datum': 1465689600, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465603200, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465516800, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465430400, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465344000, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465257600, 'Anwesend': false},{'Datum': 1465171200, 'Anwesend': false}]
```

and I want to parse this String. I tried:

```
var res = $.parseJSON(anwesendstr);
```

and:

```
var res = JSON.parse(anwesendstr);
```

But everytime I get a:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
```

Exception

Can I anybody help me to fix it?

Comment: When you get such an error, it means that your "JSON" is not valid. Similar to getting syntax errors in programming languages.

Comment: An easy way to interactively test your JSON is to use a site or tool for formatting or prettifying the JSON text. One example site is: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  By copy and pasting your JSON into this site or other similar tool, you will quickly see your JSON is not formatted correctly and has nothing to do with the code you included in your example above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSON, strings and object property names must be enclosed in double quotes. Your strings are enclosed in single quotes. Change it to:

```
[{"Datum": 1465689600, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465603200, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465516800, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465430400, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465344000, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465257600, "Anwesend": false},{"Datum": 1465171200, "Anwesend": false}]
```

and it will work.

You should use a library function to create JSON, rather than constructing it
by hand in your code, to avoid problems like this. A library will also correctly escape embedded quotes and slashes in the JSON.